# MobileFirst 7.1.0.00.20170505-1403 - NSURLErrorDomain error -1012. While Certificate pinning through iPhone

Tags: certificate, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, pinning

I followed this [Article](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/14/certificate-pinning-in-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-7-1/) to implement certificate pinning for hybrid application. The solution works well for Android but I see the following issue with iPhone.

```
err: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":0,"responseText":"","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)","invocationContext":null}
```

I have implemented exactly as mentioned in the article. I used .der format as mentioned in this code sample [here](https://github.com/IdanAdar/CertificatePinningProject/tree/master/apps/CertPinApp/certificates)

```
 // This API method must be called before any request attempt.
    WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey('MyCert.der').then(successfulPinning,failedPinning);
}

//Enable the buttons that send a request.
function successfulPinning() {
     WL.Logger.error("Certificate pinned");
}

function failedPinning() {
     WL.Logger.error("Certificate not pinned");
}
```

Comment: Does the server connection work fine in iOS if you do not enforce Certificate pinning?

Comment: Yes the server communication in HTTPS works fine if I don't enforce certificate pinning

Comment: The certificate should be in DER encoded. Can you confirm if the certificate is DER encoded and not just appended with .der extension?

Comment: Yes, it is in DER encoded, I made sure that. It is working for Android that confirms the format is correct.